# How do I output a tic tac toe table?

Tags: c++

This is the function I have so far but it doesn't produce the right output. Any help?

```
void Display(char gameBoard[][SIZE])
{

    int row, col;
    for (row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
    {
        cout << "-----------" << endl;
        for (col = 0; col < SIZE; col++)
        {
            cout << gameBoard[row][col] << " |";

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: What output does it produce? Please show us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will take a psychic guess that this is the code you actually wanted:

```
void Display(char gameBoard[][SIZE])
{
    int row, col;
    for (row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
    {
        cout << "----------" << endl;
        cout << "|";
        for (col = 0; col < SIZE; col++)
        {
            cout << gameBoard[row][col] << " |";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "----------" << endl;
}
```

Comment: @justin you need to relax. I made the change for 'cout' instead of 'count' the typo... I just didn't have min change requirement. So I made a braces change

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense now. It's unfortunate that a technical requirement caused a battle over styles.

Comment: @Jay I'm sorry that you took offense at my comment. I didn't mean to offend you. In the future, it would help to mention that you needed to meet the character count. FWIW, I didn't choose "reject and edit", but "improve edit", which means that your edit got accepted. I recognized that your edit was mostly good. Sorry again for riling emotions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    cout << "/n/t" << " | " << "/n/t" << " | " << "/t";
    cout << "/n/t" << "----------------";
```

This may work. Not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps! This will make a neat board!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {



    int SIZE = 3;

    int row, col;

    string gameBoard[3][3];

    //Initializing what gameBoard is -- I made it equal to 'X'
    for (row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
    {

        for (col = 0; col < SIZE; col++)
        {
            gameBoard[row][col] = 'X';
        }
    }


    //Outputing the table 
    for (row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
    {

        for (col = 0; col < SIZE; col++)
        {
            if (col == 0) {
                cout << gameBoard[row][col] << "  ";
            }
            else {
                cout << "  |   " << gameBoard[row][col];

            }
        }

        if (row != SIZE - 1) {
            cout << endl << "--------------------" << endl;
        }


    }
        cout << "\n";
        return 0;

}
```

If you have any questions just ask!